What's the name of this movie about a man talking about catching a fish that had the soul of a pirate?
I have a memory about watching a movie in an English class. It was a man talking about a fishing story about trying to catch a fish that is an embodiment of a dead pirate or their soul was in the fish, and everyone was trying to catch it but then the man said that if that fish was what people said it was, he baited the hook with a gold ring and then once the story was over, his son said it was bogus and he was doing something normal.
That's all I remember but I can't seem to find anything that matches what I remember, any input would be appreciated.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you watch this?  Was it live-action or animated?

Tim Burton's "Big Fish"?

@Ifurini: Looks like a match to me. "At William Bloom's wedding party, his father Edward recalls the day Will was born, claiming he caught an enormous catfish using his wedding ring as bait. Will has heard his father's fanciful tales many times, and believes they are lies. Fed up by the stories, Will has a falling out with his father. Three years later, Edward is diagnosed with cancer, prompting Will and his pregnant wife Joséphine to spend time with him in Alabama."

No soul of a pirate, but he does catch the catfish by baiting the hook with his wedding ring and his son does think his stories are nonsense.

Turning this into an answer from Ifurini's comment, Tim Burton's Big Fish matches the core details.

At William Bloom's wedding party, his father Edward recalls the day Will was born, claiming he caught an enormous catfish using his wedding ring as bait. Will has heard his father's fanciful tales many times, and believes they are lies. Fed up by the stories, Will has a falling out with his father. Three years later, Edward is diagnosed with cancer, prompting Will and his pregnant wife Joséphine to spend time with him in Alabama.

Not matching is that I can't find any reference (and I don't remember it being a plot point) to the fish having the soul of a pirate. Rather, it's just a big fish that he wants to catch (and possibly a symbol of his infidelity to Sandra with Jenny, as in the book).
